# Errors importing old projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I followed this wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs to start using eclipse while developing my ros nodes. I started importing an old node I developed a couple of weeks ago but it seems that eclipse cannot resolve subscribe. Here's my code that fails:

```
  cmd_vel_sub_ = node_.subscribe <geometry_msgs::Twist>(sub_cmd_vel, 1, boost::bind(&RosListenNode::twist_pub, this, _1));
```

and here's the error I get:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(#0), #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(#0)const, #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)const, #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(#0), const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(#0)const, const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)const, const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (*)(#0), const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, const boost::function<void (#1)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
'   bridge.cpp  /RosToPlatform-RelWithDebInfo@RosToPlatform/src line 134    Semantic Error
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47499/errors-importing-old-projects-in-eclipse/) by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) on 2012-11-06**:
A weird thing, if I remove the boost:bind call and substitute it with NULL I get no errors. So I thought it was a problem with boost but if I add

boost::bind(&RosListenNode::twist_pub, this, _1);
it doesn't result as an error.It seems like eclipse is having problems with the templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved! It was Eclipse Juno's fault. I downloaded Helios and it works just fine. I also tried Indigo but I get the same error.

---

Originally posted by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) with karma: 51 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2